# lesson containing non-ascii characters produces error when i try to run test in swirlify

Tags: r, yaml, swirl

It seems that swirlify can not handle non-ascii characters (like accented character). when trying to test or run the demo with `test_lesson()` or `demo_lesson ()`, it causes a file read error.

1: In `readLines(con)` :

```
invalid input found on input connection '..../lesson.yaml'
```

2: In `readLines(con)` :

```
incomplete final line found on '..../lesson.yaml'
```

Comment: it seems the yaml.load_file function causes this error

Answer (score 0):

the error cames from the line
con <- file(input, encoding = "UTF-8")
of the yaml.load_file function

the solution is in R studio save the yaml file with save with encoding and choose UTF-8